# Binding Service Variables in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services

Im trying to build a login modal that will update templates (just basic user info - avatars,names,etc..) across different controllers. Loosely following this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/TIfkYE?), my approach has been to bind service variables directly within my partials like this:

partial:

```
<div ng-controller="TopBarControl">
    <span>{{ userService.getInfo() }}</span>
</div>
```

service:

```
.service('userService', function($http) {

    this.userInfo = {
        isLogged: false         
    }

    this.getInfo = function() {
        return this.userInfo;
    }

    this.loginInit = function(userName, password) {
        $http.get('http://example.com/?json=get_nonce&controller=auth&method=generate_auth_cookie').success(
        function(data, status, headers, config) {
            var nonce = data.nonce;
            $http.get('http://example.com/?json=auth/generate_auth_cookie&nonce='+nonce+'&username='+userName+'&password='+password).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                if (data.status == 'ok') {
                    this.userInfo = [
                        {isLogged: true},
                        {username: data.user.username},
                        {firstName: data.user.firstname},
                        {lastName: data.user.lastname},
                        {avatar: data.user.avatar}
                    ];
                    return userInfo;
                } 
               /* handle errors and stuff*/     
        }); 
    }
})
```

controllers:

```
.controller('TopBarControl', function($scope, $modal, userService) {

    $scope.userService = userService;

    $scope.openLogin = function() {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'views/modal.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
        size: 'lg'
      });
    }   
});

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, userService) {
  $scope.login = function () {
    userService.loginInit(this.userName, this.password);
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.returnResolveVariable);
  };
};
```

So, the login works. Data is sent to the server and the correct data is successfully brought back to the app. The two-way binding sorta works - every time there is a change, the template calls back to `.getInfo()` and spits out the value of `userInfo`. The problem is that the value of userInfo never changes. I can't figure out if its something weird about how I am setting the variable in `loginInit` or if there is something that I fundamentally don't understand about how services handle variables like this.

Comment: In your example, where is the relation between the controller's `userInfo` and the service's `userInfo` variables. They aren't the same variable.

Comment: Whoops... that was commented - it was just a reference for the array I wanted to produce. I deleted it for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your use of the 'this' keyword.  The context of the 'this' keyword when you set the `this.userinfo` for the first time is different from the 'this' context in the $http handling methods.

Do something like this which captures the original context of the 'this' keyword so you can use it later:

```
.service('userService', function($http) {
    var self = this;

    this.userInfo = {
        isLogged: false         
    };

    this.getInfo = function() {
        return this.userInfo;
    };

    this.loginInit = function(userName, password) {
        $http.get('http://example.com/?json=get_nonce&controller=auth&method=generate_auth_cookie').success(
        function(data, status, headers, config) {
            var nonce = data.nonce;
            $http.get('http://example.com/?json=auth/generate_auth_cookie&nonce='+nonce+'&username='+userName+'&password='+password).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                if (data.status == 'ok') {
                   self.userInfo = [
                        {isLogged: true},
                        {username: data.user.username},
                        {firstName: data.user.firstname},
                        {lastName: data.user.lastname},
                        {avatar: data.user.avatar}
                    ];
                    return userInfo;
                } 
               /* handle errors and stuff*/     
        }); 
    };
});
```

In the above code the userInfo variable will be scoped into the inline handler function on the return of the $http call.

Understanding the 'this' keyword is pretty tricky this looks like a good introduction 'http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/' although I tend not to use it and use the revealing module pattern for my services which gets rid of this confusion see [here for an example](https://github.com/jonsamwell/angular-auto-validate/blob/master/src/services/validationManager.js)

Comment: No worries, JavaScript is a tricky thing but you will grow to love it!